# Set default language to English (US) in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, language-support

I accidentally installed Canadian English instead of US English when I did my install.  How can I set this back?

When I go to System Settings > Language Support 
English and 
English (Canada) 
are available, but English (United States), along with all other English variants, are greyed out.

"Install/Remove Languages" below does not have the granularity lower than English, so I can't select a country.  How can I install US English?

Comment: I see this is still an active question, so just to add a note: this was the result of ubuntu having Detroit listed as in Canada in 12.04, which was reported as a bug and subsequently corrected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, I ended up doing this a different way.

First I googled around for the file where this setting is stored:

`sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

Then there were a bunch of '_CA' below that I changed to '_US' like so and everything worked.

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And then USA #1.

Answer (score 8):

Under Settings>Language Support just drag the greyed out English (United States) to the top, with plain English under that.  This will activate the US locale.  You may need to check the Regional settings tab as well.

Comment: That dragging the grayed out entries is IMHO completely unintuitive. Grayed-out things usually are *inactive*, hence not-responding to mouse clicks.